# How to display the exported revision of a file from SVN repository using 'svn export'?

Tags: svn

I am exporting a file from SVN repository using 'svn export' in command prompt.

> **Command Given**
>
> **svn export --username test --password ***** http://svnserver/svn/myfile.txt@10**

The file has been exported successfully and "**Export complete.**" message had been displayed. But i need to show the message as 
"**Export complete revision 10**".

**How to display the exported revision of a file from SVN repository using 'svn export'?**

Comment: I am using svn client version 1.9.5 (installed with TortoiseSVN) and it displays "Exported revision 10" at the end. It displays "Export complete" only when exporting from working copy. Which client version are you using ?

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I am using version 1.8.14.

Comment: I am using CollabNet's version 1.8.14.